# Entity Framework Core efficient many-to-many Count?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm using EF Core to query some tables with a many-to-many relationship.

Table `Rooms`:

```
[ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Title] [nvarchar](1024) NOT NULL,
```

Table `RoomMembers`:

```
[ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[RoomId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[UserId] [nvarchar](450) NOT NULL
```

Table `AspNetUsers`:

```
[Id] [nvarchar](450) NOT NULL
<...SNIP...>
```

I'd like to return the `Room` columns along with the `Count` of the members (i.e. the number of corresponding `RoomMember` rows).

I've the tried the following:

```
var result = context
   .Rooms
   .Select(r => new 
               { 
                   Room = r, 
                   MemberCount = r.RoomMembers.Count() 
               })
   .ToList();
```

This, however, results in multiple `Count` queries.  Is there a more reasonable way to achieve the desired result in a single trip to SQL Server?

Comment: Unfortunately this seems to be one of the (many) cases that need to be addressed by *Reduce n + 1 queries* item from the [Roadmap](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/wiki/Roadmap)

Comment: Thanks @IvanStoev . Do you know of any workarounds?

Comment: Not with entity projection like yours. But non entity projection works, e.g. `Select(r => new { r.Id, r.Title, MemberCount = r.RoomMembers.Count() }`. Or even `new { Room = new Room { Id = r.Id, Title = r.Title }, MemberCount = r.RoomMembers.Count() }`. But it's quite annoying.

Comment: Thanks!  I'd mark that as the answer :)